# Rails 4: activerecord create and update return value?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm running Rails 4.2.4. One of attributes in a model gets calculated and stored by the database (PostgreSQL 9.3) upon INSERT or UPDATE. I wonder, beside calling "reload" method after activerecord create and update, is it possible to get them return the value of calculated attribute automatically? I see create adds RETURNING "id" to its SQL statement. How to add RETURNING "my_calculated_attribute" as well to the statement?

It will be great not to have that "reload" query after each create or update.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `reload` is your only option.

Comment: My digging came to the same conclusion--I hoped it was wrong. To avoid the extra `reload` query, I may just have to move the calculation into an activerecord callback.

Comment: That'll work as long as nothing other than your Rails app will touch the database. You could add a CHECK constraint to make sure the attribute is properly calculated I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. A CHECK constraint is a good idea. Don't want other clients mess up the consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Work's to me
In model.rb:

```
after_find  :convert_message_to_string;

def convert_message_to_string
    hextostr = HTMLEntities.new;

    unless hextostr.nil? or hextostr.blank?
        msg_str = hextostr.decode(self.mensagem.to_s);
        self.message = msg_str;
    end
end
```

**Important:**
self.**message** is the field name in the database

Comment: Can you explain how this answer is relevant to the question?